# Having issues when trying to link my html pages via an relative path

Tags: hyperlink, special-characters, html, relative-path

I am trying to link my home page to various other pages using the code below.

```
<a href = “./My Website.html”>Home</a>
    <a href = “./Career.html”>Career</a>
```

However when I run this and I hit the hyperlink to navigate to the page Career for example, I receive the following error:

Safari can not find the file

file:///Users/Documents/HTML/der/â€œ./Career.htmlâ€%C2%9D

I am using the free in built text editor to write the HTML on my macbook, and the to files are stored in the same folder

How do I resolve this so that my hyperlinks link to the correct file, and not add in the special characters?

It might be worth noting that when I go in to the address bar and manually remove the 'â€œ./' and 'â€%C2%9D' and refresh, my page will load as expected.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try and see if this works:

```
<a href='/MyWebsite'>Home</a>
<a href='/Career'>Career</a>
```

Do you have a screenshot of your directory?

Comment: Thank you! I tried removing the period and the error message became closer to the desired path. In the end I removed the surrounding " " and it has worked. It is now sitting in this format.  <a href =./Career.html>Career</a>